# Is there a way to shorten multiple nested for and if loops in python that ends with a list removing or appending an item?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have the following function that takes a number from a list in a list in a list (weird setup but it is necessary for the rest of the operation on my end) that sorts through all of the lists and removes a number from the innermost list. I have a few functions that append as well and I have written them in this way with a few nested for loops and if statements.

```
list = [['John', ['1','2','3']], ['Bob', ['4','5','6','7']], ['Jim', ['8','9']]]
def removeNumber(Number):
    for x in list:
        for y in x[1]:
            if y == Number:
                x[1].remove(Number)
removeNumber('5')
print(list)
```

The above block of code works, as in it removes the given number from the innermost list, but I think we can all agree it looks terrible with so many nested for loops and an if. I am pretty new to python and haven't had much practice with list comprehension.

I'm wondering if there is a way to write this using list comprehension or if there is a better way at all using another method. Better meaning fitting the mantra of "flat is better than nested". Any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: Instead of your `for y in x[1]` loop, you could do `x[1] = [n for n in x[1] if n != Number]`.  However, a lot of the complexity of this loop stems from the complexity of the data.  You may consider creating a `class` or a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to hold these things.

Comment: Also you should avoid using `list` as a variable name since it hides the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) type, which can cause hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: Also, it is usually a bug to remove items from a container that you are currently iterating over.  (e.g. Try your example with `['Bob', ['4','5','5','5','6','7']]` and see what happens.)

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop".

Comment: Well, filtering iterables, I'd probably use comprehension, even though with nesting it can get a bit funny: `def remove_number(old_list, number): return [[i, [x for x in j if x != number]] for (i, j) in old_list]` should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a bug in that code. Removing an item in `x[1]` causes the outer `for` to skip items in the list. If you want to keep the original list, do

```
def removeNumber(Number):
    for x in list:
        while Number in x[1]:
            x[1].remove(Number)
```

But in python we typically just create new lists

```
def removeNumber(Number):
    for x in list:
        x[1] = [n for n in x[1] if n != Number]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution, I made it a bit verbose in order to simplify its understanding:

```
names = [['John', ['1','2','3']], ['Bob', ['4','5','6','7']], ['Jim', ['8','9']]]

def remove_number(number_to_remove):
    for item in names:
        new_values = [value for value in item[1] if value != number_to_remove]
        item[1] = new_values

remove_number('5')
print(names)
```

I took the freedom to make variables and function name more Pythonic.

This will also help to solve a few bugs, as mentioned in comments from **0x5453**:

> It is important to note that you should avoid using list as a variable
>   name since it hides the built-in list type, which can cause
>   hard-to-debug errors.
>
> Also, it is usually a bug to remove items from a container that you
>   are currently iterating over. (e.g. Try your example with ['Bob',
>   ['4','5','5','5','6','7']] and see what happens.)

Comment: In this code, `item[1] = [...]` would be fine, because the assignment doesn't happen until the list comprehension has completed.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a list comprehension to filter out the `Number`:

```
def removeNumber(Number):
    return [[n, [e for e in l if e != Number]] for n, l in names]

names = removeNumber('5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that makes any sense, but you can use recursion to reduce number of nested loops:

```
input_list = [['John', ['1','2','3']], ['Bob', ['4','5','6','7']], ['Jim', ['8','9']]]

def removeNumber2(Number, _list):
    for x in _list:
        if Number in _list:
            _list.remove(Number)
        elif type(x) is list:
            removeNumber2(Number,  x)

removeNumber2('5', input_list)
print(input_list)
```

The same idea, cleaner code, but obviously works slowly:

```
def removeNumber3(Number, _list):
    for x in _list:
        try:
            _list.remove(Number)
        except:
            removeNumber2(Number,  x)
```